# Rasbian ICA File <Connection Error> in Cerner

Tags: raspbian, citrix-receiver

Built out a Raspbian for a Raspberry Pi Greaseboard, installed Chromium, Citrix, configured the file association path. Citirix is opening the ICA file however i get a connection error that i believe it due to SSL/encryption.

Connection Error
You do not have the proper encryption level to access this Session

I'm a noob when it comes to linux, but to my understanding it is looking for an encryption method only found in windows.... i've tried changing the encryption type to basic but no luck.

Here's a section of the ICA that i believe the error is in.

```
ICA File
[Surginet Greaseboard Prod *NAME*]
Address=Surginet Greaseboard Prod *NAME*
InitialProgram=#Surginet Greaseboard Prod *NAME*
ClientAudio=Off
TWIMode=On
ScreenPercent=100
DesiredColor=4
TransportDriver=tcp/ip
BrowserProtocol=HTTPonTCP
EncryptionLevelSession=EncRC5-128
AutoLogonAllowed=on
Username=*USERNAME
Domain=*DOMAIN
Password=Password
XmlAddressResolutionType=IPv4-Port

[EncRC5-128]
DriverNameWin32=PDC128W.DLL
DriverNameWin16=PDC128W.DLL

[Compress]
DriverName=PDCOMP.DLL
DriverNameWin16=PDCOMPW.DLL
DriverNameWin32=PDCOMPW.DLL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it might help -

```
Error: "not proper encryption level to access session"
```

For Linux:

1) Click on Network.

2) A pull down menu will occur then choose Connection.

3) Then set Encryption Level to  RC5 (128 bit).

4) Click OK.

Comment: Okay, I found this same fix online on another forum. In Raspbian there is no "netowrk" icon or application. Are you referencing something specific when you say click on network?